# What's wrong with my string comparison?

Tags: bash

I am having issues evaluating string expressions in my Bash script. This snippet of code finds the display size of the tablet connected and stores it in `$displaySize`. When `echo $displaySize` is called, it echos `1280x800`.

```
displaySize=$($adb_env -s $usb shell wm size | awk '{print $3}')
echo "$displaySize"
fifteen="1920x1080"
ten="1280x800"
if [ "$displaySize" == "$fifteen" ] ; then
    echo "Configuring a 15\""
    foo ; fi
if [ "$displaySize" == "$ten" ] ; then
    echo "Configuring a 10\""
    bar ; fi
```

The code should skip over the `$fifteen` `if` block and run through the `$ten` `if` block, but it currently skips both. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code seems to work as written after the first line. So the problem isn't with your if statements itself, but in the capturing expression and its output. (Notwithstanding "foo" and "bar" aren't obviously real commands.)

Comment: Replace `echo "$displaySize"` with `declare -p displaySize` to get a clearer idea of what value that parameter actually has.

Comment: `declare -p $displaySize` returns `: not foundnfig: line 121: declare: 1280x800`. Running it without the `$` returns `"eclare -- displaySize="1280x800`. Both of these returns are weird.

Comment: Then you have a literal carriage return in the string.

Comment: BTW, `bash -x yourscript` is helpful for catching this kind of thing.

Comment: ...as another aside -- `==` isn't actually valid syntax inside POSIX `test`; `=` is the standard-compliant string comparison operator. Bash allows `==`, but that's an extension that won't work in strictly standard-compliant shells. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: (Also, *grumble* about the unquoted expansions; consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and following its advice).

Comment: `printf 'declareSize=%q\n' "$declareSize"` is another, perhaps better way to show your variable's contents unambiguously (though that `declare -p` isn't doing the job is arguably a reasonable subject for a feature request).

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I thought I remembered `declare -p` giving a proper representation of the string. Probably confusing `bash` with Python again...

Comment: @chepner, ...actually, I thought it did too, so this one surprised me as well.

Comment: OK, to beat the dead horse one more time, `echo "${displaySize@Q}"` in `bash` 4.4 would provide a clean, sensible output of `$'1280x800\r'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variable contains a literal carriage return (which is why the cursor moves back to the beginning of the line when this character is printed). To remove it:

```
displaySize=${displaySize//$'\r'/}
```

To display it unambiguously for debugging purposes:

```
printf 'declareSize=%q\n' "$declareSize" >&2
```

Or just run `set -x` before running your script, which will generate logs like:

```
+ '[' $'1280x800\r' == 1920x1080 ']'
```

...making the issue obvious.